# Another jQuery next() issue

Tags: jquery

My HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-thumbs">

    <div class="thumb">
         <img alt="2" src="gallery/thumbs/2.jpg" class="thumbimg hand" />
    </div>

    <div class="thumb">
         <img alt="4" src="gallery/thumbs/4.jpg" class="thumbimg hand" />
    </div>

    <div class="thumb">
         <img alt="100" src="gallery/thumbs/100.jpg" class="thumbimg hand" />
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
nextphotoid = $('#gallery-thumbs img[alt="4"]').parent().parent().next("div.thumb img").attr('alt');
```

This should return 100, as that's the value of the `alt` attribute of the next image after the image with `alt='4'`, but it's not working - why not?

I've tried various combinations of `NextAll` etc. I've read around similar questions but can't get mine working - I'm obviously missing something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one parent() too many and you're on the level of #gallery-thumbs. Using next() will look for **siblings** and that's **not** what you want.

Try this:

```
nextphotoid = $('#gallery-thumbs img[alt="4"]')
    .parent()
    .next("div.thumb")
    .find('img')
    .attr('alt');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsJnh/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. I think the problem is with my structure of the HTML, as I think your code is just looking in the div with the image alt='4' in, so it never finds the other images?

Answer (score 1):

You used .next() wrongly, Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTsh8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.thumb img[alt*=4]')
.parents('div :first')
.next('div')
.children('img')
.attr('alt');
```

try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MR9h/1/)

I am really wondering when or why would you need to find "**next('alt')**", when you are already providing **one for the selector**

Comment: I hardcoded the 4 for simplicities sake, but the selector will be variable depending what image they are currently viewing, and the numbers won't necessarily be incremental. There probably is a more elegant way to achieve all of this though

Comment: If they are going to be variable how will you specify them as selectors ?

Comment: The last one they clicked is stored as a variable. If they press the next button I needed to find the 'next' one which is what my question was about it